# Invalid Relational Operator In this query

Tags: database, oracle, subquery, logic, operators

Hi good afternoon I have this query, Im trying to execute, but in brings me the Invalid Relational Operator Error in the last two lines

```
UPDATE table1 tpg
   SET comentarios = comentarios
               ||'Tipo de Cambio Inválido ó Nulo:'
               ||campo_10,
       estatus = 'RE'            
WHERE num_cia = :v_num_cia
   AND num_usuario =:v_num_usuario
   AND reg_saai =: v_Interfase
   AND estatus <>'RE'
   AND (CAMPO_10 IS NULL
   OR NOT (FU_IS_NUMBER(CAMPO_10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `FU_IS_NUMBER` is a function which returns `BOOLEAN`

Oracle SQL doesn't support `Boolean` at all so you need to change your function to return number for example (1/0).

If your function checks weather the argument is a NUMBER you can use regex. For example:

```
not regexp_like(CAMPO_10, '^-?[[:digit:]]*[.]?[[:digit:]]*$')
```

Comment: Yes, fu_is_number returns a boolean., or I have other fucntion that takes a varchar 2  and return a number, but the same error appears, campo_10 is a varchar2 but its 100% SURE that in this case are numbers, DUE TO other validations, I just have to be sure it dont comes null or have a char in it

Comment: @Carlos With the other function the same error appears because NOT <number> is not a valid logical condition (for example, "where not 1" - that's just wrong). if your second function returns number then try something like this: OR FU_IS_NUMBER2(CAMPO_10) IS NOT NULL